# print a string when the SIGINT signal is ignored

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix, sigint

I was asked to write a program which will ignore the `SIGINT` signal and print a message as well, saying it has been ignored. This is what i came up with after referring the man page for `signal` and `sigaction`.

```
    //set struct action to ignore signal
    struct sigaction action;    
    action.sa_handler=SIG_IGN;//handler set to ignore the signal
    action.sa_flags=0;
    //registeration 
    sigaction(SIGINT,&action,0);
```

But i am confused as to how i will print a message when the signal is ignored. Another option would be to define my own signal handler function but then that wouldn't be ignoring it, will it?

Answer (score 1):

if this is a homework, i'd guess the request was to catch the signal and print a message in your signal handler. The default action of SIGINT is terminating a process so i'm guessing 'ignore' means to not exit..., rather than SIG_IGN.